# Correct usage of adjectives related to amounts of time

Tags: adjectives, time

What are the correct adjectives to use when talking about amounts of time (when one needs to quantify an amount of time)? In particular, which one of the two:

little / small
big / large

For example: the airplane had a _ _ _  delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better sentence would be:

> The flight had a **long** delay.

rather than

> The flight had a **big** delay.

We usually measure time in *lengths*, so **long** and **short** are normal for this kind of sentence.

OTOH, native speakers will say things like:

> There was a **big** delay on the Brooklyn Bridge today because of a serious accident.

Comment: The `Time is Motion` Metaphor theme. See also _a short flight, a long way ahead, put it behind you_, etc. Details at http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/April05Eye.pdf and http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose the words long or short to fill in the sentence, or something referring to length, rather than big or little. I have mixed feelings about using the term amount when talking about time. For instance, I wouldn't be bothered if someone said, "It was difficult to estimate the amount of time it would take to complete the task." It sounds more natural than saying length of time. But if someone said, "Three weeks is the usual length of time needed to review an application," it sounds better to me than saying amount. I absolutely cannot stand it, though, when anyone says, "amount of people." That's just plain wrong.It drives me bonkers.

Comment: Based on the OP, are you suggesting "The airplane had an amount of delay?"  Long and short are already given as answers.  I encourage you to take the [tour] of the site and see the [help] to improve your answer, and welcome.